# How to prove $R=\{(x,y)\mid x ,y\} $ is an equivalence relation?

Tags: equivalence-relations

$R=\{(x,y)\mid x,y\; \text{are 5 bit strings with equal numbers of zeros }\}$
Prove that $R$ is an equivalence relation. How much classes does it have?

Comment: Apply the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation#Definition) checking if the relation $R$ has the desired properties-

Comment: Do you think I have not checked it?

Comment: I am thinking that you mwan that the relation is between bit strings and they are related if they have equal number of zeros. Correct? Suppose the bit strings have only a single bit each. What are the bit strings and how are they related? Can you solve the problem in that case?

Comment: And the answer is --- ?

Comment: @Somos , what do you mean?

Comment: For example,one pair 00001 and 00100.

Comment: @BerianidzeLuka Being a member for more that $2$ years you should know by now that you are expected to show your efforts on this. Not in a comment but in the question itself.

Comment: I have only ideas how to solve this, but in practice it doesn’t work

Comment: Can you state the defining properties of an equivalence relation?  Which point in particular do you find difficult?

Comment: Yeah,it should be symmetric ,reflexive and transitive to be equivalnce

Comment: Ok, good.  Now go step by step.  What about symmetry?

Comment: Oh,if we have array R , where for any (x,y) E R,  xFy and yFx

Comment: Well, almost.  [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation) is a handy reference. But, in any case, you need to apply this to the relation at hand.  If $a, b$ are two binary strings of length $5$ and $a$ has as many zeroes as $b$, does that imply that $b$ has as many zeroes as $a$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102221/discussion-between-berianidze-luka-and-lulu).

Comment: I don't want to chat about it.  Please edit your post to show some effort!  There are only three things to check, and each of them is really quite simple.

Comment: Yeah,I have already proved that this is equivalence. But what about classes? I think there is 4 classes,because we can not involve 00000 in them,there is only one object with 5 zeros and it doesn't have pair. Am I right?

Comment: No.  Every element in the set has to be exactly one equivalence class.  As you remark, $00000$ is in a class by itself, but that's fine.  Indeed, on any set you can have an equivalence relation out of $a\sim a$ with no other relations.

Comment: But...the answer isn't $5$ either.

Comment: So how can it be? We have just 5 bits,maximum is 5. We have pair for all. Can it be greater?

Comment: Try a simpler example.  Suppose you do the same thing for strings of length $1$.  How many such strings are there?  How many classes?

Comment: If 1,there can only be two lines
0
1.
0 is in only 1 line,so It think answer is 1

Comment: I don't know what "two lines" means in this context.  Just write down all the strings.  Count the equivalence classes.

Comment: How many zeroes may appear at all in a 5 length bit strings.

Comment: Let's do that for three bit strings.
000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111.
0 is in 7 of them.

Comment: For any n length string, 0 will be in 2^n - 1 strings

Comment: The underlying set is "all strings of the given length."  Not "all strings in which $0$ appears.".

Comment: Why not? Every string will create pair with itself ,but + with others. (00000,00000) (00001,00001) ... (00001,10000). I need to count them all?

Comment: I don't understand.  Once again:  there is no reason you can't have an equivalence class with only one element in it.  That's perfectly ok.   There are two strings of length $1$, for instance.  $0$ and $1$.  They are not equivalent to each other.

Comment: So how to count classes in this case?

Comment: Show some effort!  I just did length one for you.  There are two classes in that case.  Now you do length two.

Comment: There are 4 string for length 2 00 01 10 11.Then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function $f$ that assigns the number of zeroes to its input which is a bit string of length $5$.

It's straightforward that $R$ is just the 'kernel' of $f$, i.e. $(x,y)\in R\iff f(x)=f(y) $.

The number of equivalence classes of $R$ are thus corresponding to the possible values (=elements of the range) of $f$, which in this case is $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$.

Comment: So classes count is 6?

Comment: Yes, exactly. ${{{}}}$

Comment: 0 is because of having line 11111 which contains 0 zeros?

Comment: Yes, that element (and also $00000$) forms an equivalence class with a single element.

Comment: 00000 - 5
00001 - 4
00011 - 3
00111 - 2
10000 - 1
11111 - 0
something like that,right?

Comment: Yes, something like that. Just I'd rather write '$\mapsto$' to denote the function assignment in place of your '-'. Also, $10000\mapsto 4$ and not $1$.

Comment: '-' is count of zero in string

Comment: Yes, or just use the notation $f('10000')=4$.

Comment: That's right!
Thank you for the clear answer!

Comment: Note that it's a generally applicable method: if a relation is defined as (some property of two objects coincide), you can just define the function to the set of given properties.